# How to remove Gnome-fallback?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Some time ago I've upgraded my Ubuntu 11.04 to 12.04. Now I have Gnome2 as well as Gnome3.
It's a bit useless to have them both, so could u please tell me how can I remove Gnome2 safely?

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the session using this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-session-fallback
```