# How do I remove unwanted options from the splash screen? Cinnamon 1.61

Tags: gnome, uninstall, cinnamon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove session entries from LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81161/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 and cinnamon 1.61. Now, I have the following Desktop Environments as options in my login screen:

Cinnamon
Cinnamon 2D
Gnome
Gnome Classic
Gnome Classic (no effect)
KDE Plasma Worspace
Ubuntu

I would like to remove Gnome Classic, Gnome Clasic (no effect) and the KDE, how can accomplish this task?

Thank you
Mario

Answer (score 0):

possible duplicate : [How do I remove kubuntu-full and all it's applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122242/how-do-i-remove-kubuntu-full-and-all-its-applications)

For gnome check the second answer which is a possible duplicate: [How to remove and reinstall GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67764/how-to-remove-and-reinstall-gnome-3)

For gnome classic possible duplicate:
[How to remove Gnome-fallback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179376/how-to-remove-gnome-fallback)

I copied the commands for you. However check the links to know what will happend if you used these commands since these commands may remove programs/dependencies you may want to keep.

KDE

```
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop
```

*EDIT*:  **WAIT** Before using the last 2 commands I need someone else to tell if removing the gnome would also remove the cinnamon desktop !! if yes then probably you dont want to use it.

Gnome Classic

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-session-fallback
```

Gnome

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell
```